# Binding Angular data after a jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-animate

I'm running a jQuery animation, after which I need to update the value of the data inside the animated element.

For some reason I cannot do this

```
$scope.myVar = "START";

$("#div").delay(100).animate({
    top: '50px'
}, {
    duration: $scope.speed,
    easing: $scope.ease,
    complete: function () {
        $scope.myVar = "FINISHED";
    }
});
```

When logging the variable it does update; however, this is not reflected on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [`$scope.apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply).
From angular documentation

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the (very) quick reply. It seems a novice question so hope it helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use $timeout:

```
$timeout(function () {
  //$scope.myvar = "FINISHED";
}, 0);
```

it works but I don't know how much it's elegant...